# Prevent eclipse from removing whitespaces

Tags: eclipse

How can I prevent Eclipse from removing whitespace within a line?

Example:

```
final Map<String, String> capitalOf = new HashMap<String, String>();
capitalOf.put("France",       "Paris");
capitalOf.put("Italy",        "Rom");
capitalOf.put("Switzerland",  "Bern");
```

gets becomes after calling `Format` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>)

```
final Map<String, String> capitalOf = new HashMap<String, String>();
capitalOf.put("France", "Paris");
capitalOf.put("Italy", "Rom");
capitalOf.put("Switzerland", "Bern");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the behavior of the Java Formatter in the white space section of the Preferences (Java - Code Style - Formatter).

[image: Formatter Preferences]

In your case you will have to rely on the formatter tags to turn off the formatting of your code:

```
    @formatter:off
    capitalOf.put("France",       "Paris");
    capitalOf.put("Italy",        "Rom");
    capitalOf.put("Switzerland",  "Bern");
    @formatter:on
```

For this to work, the off/on tags have to be enabled as shown below:

[image: Formatter Off/On tags]

Comment: I have not found a configuration item for my case there.